# PHP not closing Mysql connections and reaching max connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a site that is about 6 years old, and in the last 6 months, we have been getting the same issue over and over with maxing out the mysql connections.

Now every couple of days the site becomes unavailable because there are no sql connections left.  As it's on a shared server, I need to get the host company to flush the connections.

Here's what I tried:

- Made sure every page now has a close on it
- Upgraded to PHP7 and converted to mysqli
- Pulled my hair out

Everywhere I look, it says not to use Persistant connections - I am not explicitly using them - and that PHP will automatically release connections after the page completes - hmmm...

The host company is usually really helpful, but not over this.  So I have 2 questions...

1. What is causing the connections to not close either on my mysqli_close() or on PHP exit?  Perhaps pages are aborting or too slow and failing?
2. Why don't the connections close themselves... It can be hours later that I report it to the host company and they flush the connections... Why are they not bring tidied up? In the mean time the site is unavailable...

Please help..

Cris.

---

Ah... I have just read the host company responses more clearly... (it's been a hectic few days) They say *"The issue that is the database server on the shared hosting platform is designed to lock the database once it hits it's maximum allowed connections, so it never closes any connections once it hits 25 simultaneous connections. "*

So the question is why am I hitting 25 connections?  Is is that I'm holding connections open for slow loading pages and so limiting the number available?

---

Comment: This is not normal. Connections should not need to be cleaned up. How many connections are you allowed to have, and how many PHP processes do you have running?

Comment: Probably about time to upgrade your hosting package or get on your own server.  I don't foresee this being a PHP problem, but a limited resources problem.

Comment: Ah... I have just read the host company responses more clearly...  (it's been a hectic fre days)

They say "The issue that is the database server on the shared hosting platform is designed to lock the database once it hits it's maximum allowed connections, so it never closes any connections once it hits 25 simultaneous connections. "

Comment: I do not recommend to just get your own server over this, unless you know how to manage a server, which is, to be frank, a pain and may end up costly if you turn out not to be prepared for all attacks and eventualities that are out there.

Comment: There are only 2 reasons this should have changed recently: 1 - **your site** has more activity than it used to - if that is the case then upgrading to a better hosting plan for more capacity makes sense; 2 - **other sites** on the same server have more activity than they used to, causing indirect problems for your site - if that is the case then upgrading to a hosting plan that has better balancing between servers and/or better protection between accounts makes sense. I'd give you my personal recommendation but that is (rightly so) frowned upon. But there ARE some good hosts out there.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you open a mysqli connection

```
$mysqli = connect_db();
```

you have to explicitly close it or they linger around and mysql server eventually is unhappy

```
$mysqli->close();
```

While explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional, doing so is recommended. This will immediately return resources to PHP and MySQL, which can improve performance.  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: Yes, thanks... I close them all...  But I open once at the top of the page and close at the bottom...

Starting to suspect that some pages take too long to load, and so keep the connection open longer then needed...  

Might break them up and close as soon as read, then re-open if necessary...